# Returning response with the image contents NOT WORKING

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10, laravel-storage

I want to load an image as avatar of user like this at the Blade:

```
<img src="{{ route('adm.profile.details.show.avatar') }}" alt="user-img" title="Avatar" class="img-circle img-thumbnail img-responsive">
```

So it loads the image via this route:

```
Route::get('/avatar/display', [AdminController::class, 'showAvatar'])->name('adm.profile.details.show.avatar');
```

And then in the Controller:

```
public function showAvatar()
    {
        $avatarPath = "adm/avatars/" . auth()->user()->usr_name. ".jpg";
        $defaultAvatarPath = asset("assets/img/adm.png"); // Path to default avatar image in the public directory

        if (Storage::exists($avatarPath)) {
            $contents = Storage::get($avatarPath);
        } else {
            $contents = file_get_contents($defaultAvatarPath);
        }

        $headers = ['content-type' => 'image/jpeg'];
        return response($contents, 200, $headers);
    }
```

But now when the image with user name of user does not exist, it should load the default picture of user which is placed at `public/assets/img/adm.png` but somehow it does not work out!

So if you know, what's going wrong here and how can I load the default image properly please let me know...

Comment: You're outputting a `.png` image with an `image/jpeg` header?

Comment: @brombeer Oop! I fixed this and image itself is jpg type but still not showing!

Comment: asset will return url so you have to use public_path("assets/img/adm.png")

Comment: @JohnLobo Still not working

Comment: @brombeer This is better practice for returning the avatar of admin